# Rails - how to combine incompatible statements with OR (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

There is a Project model and Payment model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

It is quite easy for me to combine queries for colums with either `or` OR `and`.

```
Project.where(projects[:created_at].gt(6.months.ago).or(projects[:updated_at].gt(1.month.ago)))
```

The reason for using Arel is that the exact columns, operators and values comes from the user and Arel operators match very nicely with what the user can select.

However, if I want to combine this with data from another associated table, then I just cannot figure out what to do. ActiverRecord requires `OR` to be structurally compatible, so I cannot do:

`Project.where(projects[:created_at].gt(6.months.ago)).or(Project.joins(:payments))`

Something like this:
`Project.where(projects[:created_at].gt(6.months.ago).or(projects.join(payments).on(projects[:id].eq(payments[:project_id]))))`

raises exception: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column.

One way I was able to do it was something like:
`Project.where(projects[:created_at].gt(6.months.ago)).or(Project.where(id: Project.joins(:payments).select(:id)))`

which generated SQL
`SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE (("projects"."created_at" > '2019-08-19 09:11:22.064298') OR "projects"."id" IN (SELECT "projects"."id" FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."project_id" = "projects"."id"))`

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way? Please there might be 10+ such clauses combined, involving multiple tables, using `include` on all the possible tables to make all individual clauses compatible is likely to be too expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't keep your joins consistent across conditions? For example in Rails 5+ you can write:

```
Project.where(some_field: '12').joins(:payments)
       .or(
           Project.where(payments: {id: '1'}).joins(:payments)
       )
```

Which would generate SQL like:

```
SELECT projects.* FROM projects
INNER JOIN payments ON (payments.project_id = project.id)
WHERE projects.some_field = 12 OR payments.id = 1
```

---

*Note:*

Using your structurally incompatible example in the OP, you can simply add a join to the first condition to make it compatible:

```
Project.where(projects[:created_at].gt(6.months.ago)).joins(:payments).or(Project.joins(:payments))
```

Comment: I have considered it, but as I mentioned in the question, I am combining multiple such clauses (or conditions, if you will). So, I could end up with needing to join 4+ tables to the original `projects` table.

Would you say that in such a case, I am better off joining the tables and running the query like you said? Or the way I mentioned ie `Project.where(projects[:created_at].gt(6.months.ago)).or(Project.where(id: Project.joins(:payments).select(:id)))`

I am not very experienced with SQL, but the few times I have tried, 4 is the number of joins where the performance took a big hit.

Comment: @arunt I would recommend using joins over subqueries for the sake of simplicity and taking advantage of indexes on columns. That being said, there's no perfect answer; each can be the fastest approach in certain scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted your answer as it seems to be a good alternative. I guess there is no single solution for best performance.